Asymptotics of number of running maxima of iid random variables
Let $\{X_i\}_{i \geq 1}$ be a sequence of iid non atomic random variables, that is, their CDF has no jump discontinuities.
Given a realisation $\omega$ of the random variables, we say that $X_i (\omega)$ is a running  maximum if $X_i (\omega) \geq  X_j(\omega)$ for all $j < i$.
Question: Let $M_n$ denote the number of running maximums up to time $n$. Is it true that
$$M_n \asymp\log n$$
almost surely as $n \to \infty$?
That is, do there exist deterministic constants $c, C > 0$ such that for almost every $\omega$ and for all large enough $N$, possibly depending on $\omega$, we have
$$c \log n \leq M_n (\omega) \leq C \log n$$
for all $n \geq N(\omega)$?

The number of left-to-right maxima between $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is distributed as the number of cycles in the random permutation in $S_n$. This was studied a lot. See, for instance, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.04906 and references therein

In particular, the sequence $M_n$ is given by $M_n=B_1+\dots+B_n$ where the $B_i$ are independent random variables, $B_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(1/i)$. (The events that $X_i$ is a running maximum are independent for different $i$.)

@JamesMartin They are independent?

@mathworker They are independent. The relative ordering of the first $n$ values (which is uniform on the $n!$ possibilities) carries no information about whether or not the $(n+1)$st is larger than all of them.

@JamesMartin Ok, but you have to be careful. If running maximum was defined with strict inequality and the distribution is uniform over ${1,2}$, say, then the conditional probability that [$X_3$ is a running maximum] given that [$X_2$ is] is equal to $0$, but the unconditional probability is positive.

@mathworker21 You are welcome be as careful as you like! I was just giving you a brief indication of why it's true. I remember it as an exercise from the first course I took in probability, from Frank Kelly in 1992. Indeed, the non-atomic case is less elegant....

@JamesMartin Thanks. And I think you mean "atomic" at the end.

yes, that's what I meant :)  $,,,,,$

@JamesMartin Ah, that’s a very nice independence argument.
